# Проблемы с получением кода страницы

Tags: python, парсер, python-3.6, facebook, обфускация

Я занимаюcь парсингом facebook, и столкнулась с одной проблемой. Если я смотрю код страницы, то вижу красивое html дерево, разбитое на блоки и т.д. Но, когда я получаю soup, то мне приходит, как мне кажется, обфусцированный код страницы. Если вы сталкивались с таким, что вы делали, или, возможно, у вас есть какие-то хорошие источники, где можно понятнее новичку почитать про обфускацию. Буду рада всему.
Пример кода, где я получаю soup.

```
if not self.browser.is_free():
    self.browser.driver.get(url)
#   js_code = "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML"
#   your_elements = self.browser.driver.execute_script(js_code)
    html = self.browser.driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    return soup
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего там половина контента генериться на JavaScript после загрузки страницы и надо использовать Selenium или ещё какой-то движок, который сможет полноценно эмулировать браузер с JS.